# OAuth, Custom Login, or Both

Tags: angularjs, oauth

I am struggling to determine if I should use only oAuth, develop a custom login, or both for my Angularjs site. What have others done/what were some of your reasons for the decisions you made?

I can see the benefits of oAuth only, and moving the storage of credentials off my app, but it comes with the risk of users not having a Google, FaceBook, Twitter, LinkedIn account.

Comment: So I take it your looking at this from a login perspective?  I think most people have a Google+ account, some probably don't even know they do.

Comment: You need both as definitely there is a risk of users not having a Google, FaceBook, Twitter, LinkedIn account.

Comment: Do you tend to use a service such as oAuth.io or do you tend to develop it all custom? Are there any "good practices" or blogs/documentation you tend to follow?

Comment: you can use both, OAuth support custom login as well :) [sattelizer](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From login perspective, you just need "credentials" of an unique user and this user can provide it to your service in any way. So it depends on more aspects such as: you want to publish something to existing accounts of user (Facebook, Google+...) or sync information between them and your service.